# Linking Qt Libraries to a Cmake project (in eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, qt, libraries

so what I'm trying to do is utilize a simple Qt application IN eclipse without using the eclipse QT plugin by linking the required libraries through the GCC C++ Linker. However, I have been unable to locate the exact name of the library to use, or which libraries will be necessary. I've located the path of the Qt library my application seems to be accessing, but I continue to get an error when building that just says "-lqt" doesn't exist/can't find, etc.

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm building a simple game in OGRE for a project at the uni and wanted to use a Qt application for the GUI. Well, I didn't necessarily *want* too, but our professor wishes us to do so. Please don't suggest that I simply embed an Ogre widgit into my Qt application as this isn't an opti

Any ideas?

Thanks <3

Comment: Is this question about CMake or configuring inside Eclipse? If you are using CMake, you really don't want to make any additional configuration inside eclipse, as it'll be overwritten on the next regeneration. See http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects for help how to configure your CMakeLists.txt for linking against Qt

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are using `CMake` then it should take care of everything provided that you [instructed it](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Compiling_Qt4_apps_with_CMake) to do so. [phb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199746/linking-qt-libraries-to-a-cmake-project-in-eclipse/10199852#comment13096963_10199746) provided [a link](http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects) to even better instructions.

First step is to instruct the `CMake` that we need Qt for our project. This is done with (you can specify individual parts that are needed as well):

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
```

If `Qt` is not found in the typical locations (e.g. `QTDIR` is not set) - `cmake` will fail.

You also have to instruct `CMake` to use Qt include paths and set certain compiler definitions:

```
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
```

Finally, for each target you need to tell that you'd like to link with Qt libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(foo ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

You might also want to process your headers and will have to process the user interface files with `moc`. For the details please refer to the provided links.

In addition to provided links you can have a look at the comments at the top of  `FindQt4.cmake` file.